# Trigger event to click a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden link and a button.
I want when users click on the button they will go to the link.
Why I'm not just show the link so users can click through the link because I don't want users see the link that appear at the bottom of browser.

```
<a id="stack" href="http://stackoverflow.com/"></a>
<button id="goTo">Stackoverflow</button>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I like to know what URL I'm going to before I click on a link. Why don't you want your users to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#goTo").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = $("#stack").attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thak you for the answer. But when I click the button the browser load the same page.

Comment: It loads a new page with the url in the href of the a#stack so if you change this href it will change the destination

Comment: Yes, I see at the bottom of the browser _waiting for stackoverflow..._ after I click the button but I still on the same page. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tJwxp)

Comment: Yes it's because on codepen the rendering is made in an iframe on an other domain and you can't reload the parent window in JS from an iframe because of security issue (if you check your console you'll see a message about it when you click)

Answer (score 0):

Add simple jquery to relay the click on the button. You can leave the `a` link out.

```
$("#goTo").click(function(){
 window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
}
```